# How do you get thumbnails to show up in the admin edit post?

Tags: themes, admin, post-thumbnails

I tried to add thumbnail support to my theme

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size(133, 133, true);
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) );
```

So this isnt working, or at least I'm not sure how this should work, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks flawed:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) );
```

Do you see the post thumbnail box on pages? If so, you have just overwritten the support on posts with the second declaration.

Better:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
```

Comment: Doesn't the first generic add theme support (in the OP code) add it to post and pages, negating the need to apply it to posts and pages separately? That's what I was mentioning in my reply, albeit not so clearly.... been a long day! But yeah, the page declaration could be over-writing the 2 previous declarations.... only the first 2 lines would be needed

Answer (score 2):

your code is proper, at least the first 2 lines.... don't think the last 2 lines are needed

The feature is actually called featured image in the edit post screen, even though the code calls it thumbnails. Bit of a terminology change over versions

If the 'featured image' option is not visible toward the bottom right, then up toward the top right you should see 'screen options', click that and see if the featured image is checked to be displayed

And just to be sure, you added that code to functions.php correct?

Comment: Mine usually shows at the bottom right of the screen

Comment: I'll clarify my answer...that does sound wrong.... I had meant screen options was top right

Comment: (wipes forhead) i thought my wp install was flawed